# How to build and host a yesod web application

Tags: hosting, yesod

What is the best way to build and host yesod applications?
I have already tried different tutorials but without success.

Kind regards
Joachim

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What exactly do you want to do, what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: If you need to use nginx, you can get that to work in a couple of ways explained [in the yesod wiki](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Deploying-via-Keter-alongside-Nginx) (which I sincerly must thank pbrisbin for writing). Personally, I've got the double-proxy setup, although plainly using just keter would be a bit more neat.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the recommended deployment process is via [keter](https://github.com/snoyberg/keter/blob/master/README.md). I also use and enjoy this method myself.